# Volume of a subset of R^n

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Question:
Compute volume of the set A:
$A = \{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \text{ | }  0 ≤ x_i ≤ 1, \sum_ix_i = 1\}$

Try:
We know volume is basically integrating 1 over the set. I suppose fubini’s theorem is to be used but I can’t set up. How do I use $\sum_ix_i = 1$?

Def of Volume:
Volume vol(C) of a set C is the integral
of the constant function 1 over C.

Comment: Are we computing the $n$-volume? That's quite simple - it's $0$. If not, please provide a more precise definition of "volume".

Comment: If you meant $\sum_i x_i\le 1$, the answer is in the list of Related questions

Comment: @MarkSaving Added definition of volume. Why would it be 0? For a 3 variable case doesn’t it refer to the part of a plane and then volume would be area of that part? Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: @user925032 The 3D volume of a plane is 0. Saying that it's the integral of the constant function 1 doesn't actually solve the problem of definitions, since the question is "which integral?"

Comment: Take n=1.  Then your set is a single point and has length zero.  Take $n=2$.  Then your set is a line segment, and has area zero.  Take $n=3$.  Then your set is a triangle and has volume zero.

Comment: @GEdgar I see. Just being curious is there a way to find the “area” for n=3 and then for general n. (Basically volume of n-1 dimension)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by focusing on one variable (e.g. $x_n$) and letting that "run free", then the next one can only be from $(0, 1 - x_n)$, the one after that from $(0, 1 - x_n - x_{n-1})$ and so on. So the total integral is
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x_n} \int_0^{1-x_{n-1}-x_n}...\int_0^{1-{\sum_{i=j}^n x_i}} ... \int_0^{1-{\sum_{i=3}^n x_i}} \int_0^{1-{\sum_{i=2}^n x_i}} dx_1 dx_2 ... dx_j ... dx_{n-2} dx_{n-1} dx_n.
$$
You can either brute-force calculate this or try to approach it a bit more geometrically by focusing on some low dimensional cases.
Some examples for specific values of $n$:
$$
n=1: \quad \int_0^1 dx_1 = 1 \\
n=2: \quad \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x_2}  dx_1 dx_2 = \int_0^1 (1-x_2) dx_2 = \frac{1}{2} \\
n=3: \quad \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x_3} \int_0^{1-x_3-x_2} dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 = \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x_3} (1-x_3 - x_2) dx_2 dx_3 = \int_0^1 \frac{(1-x_3)^2}{2} dx_3 = \frac{1}{6}
$$

Comment: What are you computing? Have you tried to write down your own expression for $n=2$? Whatever you are computing, you need to check those indices.

Comment: For $n=2$ it's $$\int_0^1 1-x_1 dx_1 = \frac{1}{2},$$ for $n=3$ it's $$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x_3} \int_0^{1-x_2-x_3} dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 = \frac{1}{6}$$ and so on. In the expression I wrote down I had already simplified the innermost integral which yes, leads to difficulties in the case for $n=2$. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Take the simplex whose vertices are the origin and the standard basis vectors.
The volume of the simplex is $1/n!$.
Now regard it as a pyramid whose summit is the origin and base is the area you want.
The centre of the base is $(1/n,1/n,...,1/n)$ so the height of the pyramid is $1/\sqrt n$.
The volume is base × height / n = 1/n!, so $$base =\frac{n\sqrt n}{n!}$$